# Click eventListener runs only once

Tags: javascript, html, events

Can you explain why the button on this simple webpage runs only once? Why do repeated clicks not work? Has it something to do with the way I'm adding the result to the body of the page? I can get it to work by creating a new Div and adding the answer to that instead, but I would just like to understand the reason why this code is not working?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {

            margin: 0.6rem;
            padding: 0.4rem;

        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="percentage">
        <input type="number" id="part">
        <input type="number" id="whole">
        <button id="calculatePercentage">Calculate percentage</button>
        <div id="answerPercentage"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function howManyPercent(part, whole) {
            return part / whole * 100;
        }

        document.getElementById("calculatePercentage").addEventListener("click", function () {

            let partInput = document.getElementById("part");
            let wholeInput = document.getElementById("whole");

            let myAnswer = howManyPercent(partInput.value, wholeInput.value);

            document.body.innerHTML += myAnswer + '%';

        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML += myAnswer + '%';` is the culprit here. By doing this, you're actually rewriting the entire body, which means that the `button` that was there before is now a new button, rendered with new html, and none of hte javascript you applied to the old button is there anymore

Comment: I think there would be the javascript error occurred so that the javascript doesn't continue to excute.

Comment: @TKol Got it! Feel free to make this the answer. If possible, could you point out if there is a way to bind the click event listener even to such a situation in which the body keeps refreshing like this?

Comment: I'll work on a more complete answer

Comment: Use the correct element to show the answer. document.getElementById("answerPercentage").innerText = myAnswer + '%';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code as you had it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>

<style>
    div {

        margin: 0.6rem;
        padding: 0.4rem;

    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="percentage">

    <input type="number" id="part">
    <input type="number" id="whole">

    <button id="calculatePercentage">Calculate percentage</button>

    <div id="answerPercentage"></div>

</div>



<script>

    function howManyPercent(part, whole) {

        return part / whole * 100;

    }

    document.getElementById("calculatePercentage").addEventListener("click", function () {

        let partInput = document.getElementById("part");
        let wholeInput = document.getElementById("whole");

        let myAnswer = howManyPercent(partInput.value, wholeInput.value);

        document.body.innerHTML += myAnswer + '%';

    })





</script>

</body>

</html>
```

So I put `3` and `3` into each input and it rerenders with `100%` underneath the inputs.

But what happens is your code `document.body.innerHTML += myAnswer + '%';` is rewriting the entire body from scratch with new html, so any javascript you ran on the old html dom elements is gone now.

What I would recommend instead is to use your `<div id="answerPercentage"></div>` instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>

<style>
    div {

        margin: 0.6rem;
        padding: 0.4rem;

    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="percentage">

    <input type="number" id="part">
    <input type="number" id="whole">

    <button id="calculatePercentage">Calculate percentage</button>

    <div id="answerPercentage"></div>

</div>



<script>

    function howManyPercent(part, whole) {

        return part / whole * 100;

    }

    document.getElementById("calculatePercentage").addEventListener("click", function () {

        let partInput = document.getElementById("part");
        let wholeInput = document.getElementById("whole");

        let myAnswer = howManyPercent(partInput.value, wholeInput.value);

        document.getElementById('answerPercentage').innerHTML = myAnswer + '%';

    })





</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is there any way to have the eventListener keep working even if I refresh the body like this? Isn't there a way of binding events to dynamic content?

Comment: no, you'd have to rebind it every time you change the body if you want to do the whole `document.body.innerHTML += ` route. You're literally deleting the element from the dom and then rewriting it back in, there's no way for the event listener to still be there unless you reapply it every time

Comment: Oh, actually, you know what, I'm kind of wrong. There is one way to do it, but I only know how to do it with jquery. `$(document).on('click', '#calculatePercentage', function(){});`

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#calculatePercentage', func` says, `when the document is clicked, check that the element that was clicked matches the selector #calculatePercentage, and if it does run the function`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating whole body, you can update `document.getElementById("answerPercentage").innerHTML` only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {

            margin: 0.6rem;
            padding: 0.4rem;

        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="percentage">
        <input type="number" id="part">
        <input type="number" id="whole">
        <button id="calculatePercentage">Calculate percentage</button>
        <div id="answerPercentage"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function howManyPercent(part, whole) {
            return part / whole * 100;
        }

        document.getElementById("calculatePercentage").addEventListener("click", function () {

            let partInput = document.getElementById("part");
            let wholeInput = document.getElementById("whole");

            let myAnswer = howManyPercent(partInput.value, wholeInput.value);

            document.getElementById("answerPercentage").innerHTML = myAnswer + '%';

        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```